# Do I need to update ApexClass?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

[image]We have an ApexClass that references the SourceSystemID field (FinServ__SourceSystemId__c)) on Account.

The Source System ID field (FinServ__SourceSystemId__c) is a Managed text field, 100 characters in length, and an external ID. The structure/and data type of this Source System ID field is not changing in Salesforce, but the data is.

At present, all Source System ID's conform to one of two formats:

1. The Source System ID is all numbers, ranging from 1-4 digits
   Example: 1256, 87, 909, 2389
2. The Source System ID begins with the letter "H", and is followed by 1-4 digits
   Example:  H1256, H87, H909, H2389

We will soon change the format of all data in the Source System ID field:

Current Format: 1256, New Format:  Person-4594-1256
Current Format: 87, New Format: Person-4594-87
Current Format: H909, New Format: Household-4594-909
Current Format: H2389, New Format: Household-4594-2389

Does the ApexClass have to be updated to account for the new format of the data in the SourceSystemID field?

Comment: Please copy/paste code as text instead of (or in addition to) screenshots. An image of text with no accompanying actual text is not good accessibility-wise for folks with screen readers. Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox or code editor. (And in cases like this one, the effective/perceived font size of the code in your screenshot is smaller than the native Stack Exchange `code format` font which makes it harder to read.)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a test class that is mocking data to be used by the testmethods

**YES - you have to change the testclass mocking method**

- If you have runtime enforcement through validation rules or managed package validation rules (via some configuration setting) that requires the `SourceSystemId` to be in the new format.
- You have downstream code that gets executed by the testemthod that cares about the format of the `SourceSystemId` and would fail if not in the new format.

**NO -- you don't have to change the testclass mocking method**

- If your code under test doesn't care about the old format and the new format is just a convention you are enforcing for real production data.

So, the answer is *it depends*.  Assuming your dev environment mirrors PROD in terms of validation rules and other relevant configuration, then just run the test as is - if it breaks, you'll know you fell into one of the `YES - you have to change the testcalss mocking method` example reasons.